# Remove Items (or pages) during '@media print' style sheet

Tags: html, css

Right now I have my @media print style sheet to hide various objects by ID/class, such as

```
    @media print {
           #header, #navbar, #navbar, #toolbar, #footer, .title {
        visibility:hidden;
        display:none;
          } 
}
```

At print preview, it does hide these objects but the space they take up is still there, forcing what I WANT to print to be on page 2, with a blank page 1 and blank page 3. If there is a way to have the only page 2 shows at the print screen, or a way to truncate the stuff I don't want as oppose to just hiding them, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding !important

Comment: so @media print { #header, #navbar, #navbar, #toolbar, #footer, .title { visibility:hidden !important ; display:none !important; } } ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `visibility:hidden` leaves the space the element would occupy, while `display:none` does not show that space.

You want to use:

```
@media print {
 #header, #navbar, #navbar, #toolbar, #footer, .title {
  display:none !important;
 } 
}
```

Of course this has been addressed before:
[What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)